# Optimization performance winform app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

is there any way how can I improve the performance of my app by some utilits? I am writting app in C# with .Net framework 3.5 and it is app which shows logs files which has many lines (they are text files about 200MBs) and It can has 500MB RAM memory and about 10s loaded. Can I get some of these performance down? Ofcourse it can be doing by better code but I saw something with NGEN, GAC, ... Can this help too for my kind of app? Thanks

**Edit**

Example of log file:

```
110331 052205 4969 [DB] fbba246f-bbe8-43b0-b8ca-f53bb90e8b51 Q   SELECT GRAFIKON.ID,GRAFIKON.NADRAZENYGRAFIKONID,GRAFIKON.PLATNOSTOD,GRAFIKON.PLATNOSTDO,GRAFIKON.OBJEDNAVANIOD,GRAFIKON.OBJEDNAVANIDO,GRAFIKON.NAZEV,GRAFIKON.PROOBJEDNAVANI,GRAFIKON.ARCHIV,GRAFIKON.UZAVREN,GRAFIKON_0.Nazev,GRAFIKON_1.PlatnostOd FROM GRAFIKON LEFT OUTER JOIN GRAFIKON GRAFIKON_0 ON  GRAFIKON.NADRAZENYGRAFIKONID = GRAFIKON_0.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN GRAFIKON GRAFIKON_1 ON  GRAFIKON.NADRAZENYGRAFIKONID = GRAFIKON_1.Id WHERE (GRAFIKON.PROOBJEDNAVANI = 1)

110331 052205 6062 [DB] fbba246f-bbe8-43b0-b8ca-f53bb90e8b51 Q   0s 109ms

110331 052205 6375 [DB] acdbcdb6-aa3a-460a-a323-0be7c4512c14 Q   SELECT NASTAVENI.ID,NASTAVENI.KLIC,NASTAVENI.HODNOTA,NASTAVENI.INFO,NASTAVENI.SKUPINA,NASTAVENI.TEXTAREA FROM NASTAVENI WHERE (NASTAVENI.KLIC = 'ARTICLE_AFTER_OPEN')

110331 052205 6688 [DB] acdbcdb6-aa3a-460a-a323-0be7c4512c14 Q   0s 31ms

110331 052205 7625 [DB] 9fd6ec6b-4844-44fe-8367-26c580ca8493 Q   SELECT NASTAVENI.ID,NASTAVENI.KLIC,NASTAVENI.HODNOTA,NASTAVENI.INFO,NASTAVENI.SKUPINA,NASTAVENI.TEXTAREA FROM NASTAVENI WHERE (NASTAVENI.KLIC = 'GRAPHICON_CLOSED_SMS_TEXT')

110331 052205 7625 [DB] 9fd6ec6b-4844-44fe-8367-26c580ca8493 Q   < 15ms

110331 065945 6813 [DB] 6387c3a4-33a5-4dfd-92d3-f4a8d00c910d Q   SELECT GRAFIKON.ID,GRAFIKON.NADRAZENYGRAFIKONID,GRAFIKON.PLATNOSTOD,GRAFIKON.PLATNOSTDO,GRAFIKON.OBJEDNAVANIOD,GRAFIKON.OBJEDNAVANIDO,GRAFIKON.NAZEV,GRAFIKON.PROOBJEDNAVANI,GRAFIKON.ARCHIV,GRAFIKON.UZAVREN,GRAFIKON_0.Nazev,GRAFIKON_1.PlatnostOd FROM GRAFIKON LEFT OUTER JOIN GRAFIKON GRAFIKON_0 ON  GRAFIKON.NADRAZENYGRAFIKONID = GRAFIKON_0.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN GRAFIKON GRAFIKON_1 ON  GRAFIKON.NADRAZENYGRAFIKONID = GRAFIKON_1.Id WHERE (GRAFIKON.PROOBJEDNAVANI = 1)

110331 065945 7438 [DB] 6387c3a4-33a5-4dfd-92d3-f4a8d00c910d Q   0s 62ms
```

First 12 numbers are date and time (then it is ms I can drop it), then modul, information, Q as query and then next information or time how long it takes to execute. And this is my code:

```
   private Record GetRecordFromString(string strWithRecord)
    {
        Record newRecord = new Record();
        try
        {
            if (strWithRecord.Length < 24)
            {
                newRecord.Prikaz = strWithRecord;
                return newRecord;
            }
            if(!CheckIfFirstCharsAreDateTime(strWithRecord))
            {
                newRecord.Prikaz = strWithRecord;
                return newRecord;
            }

            newRecord.Datum = ChangeDateFormat(strWithRecord.Substring(0, 6));
            newRecord.Cas = ChangeTimeFormat(strWithRecord.Substring(7, 6));
            strWithRecord = strWithRecord.Remove(0, 20);

            int tempInt = strWithRecord.IndexOf(']');
            newRecord.Modul = strWithRecord.Substring(0, tempInt);

            strWithRecord = strWithRecord.Remove(0, tempInt + 2);
            if (newRecord.Modul.StartsWith("DB"))
            {
                if (Char.IsUpper(strWithRecord[0]))
                {
                    newRecord.Informace = strWithRecord;
                }
                else
                {
                    tempInt = strWithRecord.IndexOf(' ');
                    newRecord.Informace = strWithRecord.Substring(0, tempInt);
                    strWithRecord = strWithRecord.Remove(0, tempInt + 1);

                    tempInt = strWithRecord.IndexOf(' ');
                    newRecord.Priznak = strWithRecord.Substring(0, tempInt);
                    strWithRecord = strWithRecord.Remove(0, tempInt + 1);

                    newRecord.Prikaz = strWithRecord;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                newRecord.Informace = strWithRecord;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return newRecord;
    }

private bool CheckIfFirstCharsAreDateTime(string stringToCheck)
{
    if (!Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[0]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[1]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[2]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[3]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[4]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[5]) || !Char.IsWhiteSpace(stringToCheck[6]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[7]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[8]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[9]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[10]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[11]) || !Char.IsNumber(stringToCheck[12]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

private string ChangeDateFormat(string strWithDate)
{
    try
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWithDate))
            return "";
        char[] arrayOfChars = strWithDate.ToCharArray();
        strWithDate = arrayOfChars[4].ToString() + arrayOfChars[5].ToString() + "." + arrayOfChars[2].ToString() + arrayOfChars[3].ToString() + ".20" + arrayOfChars[0].ToString() + arrayOfChars[1].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
    }
    return strWithDate;
}

    private string ChangeTimeFormat(string strWithTime)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWithTime))
            return "";
        strWithTime = strWithTime.Insert(2, ":");
        strWithTime = strWithTime.Insert(5, ":");

        return strWithTime;
    }
```

**Edit2**
[Profiler file](http://filefactory.com/file/cb1bc90/n/prvni_result_na_vsechno.app6results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGEN only helps JIT performance; now, you can *try* that, but given your scenario it sounds to me like you are throttled on IO performance. The simplest "fix" I can suggest is: fit a faster disk (an SSD or something).

Of course, you aren't showing how *exactly* you are reading the files; I would suggest a `StreamReader` and `ReadLine()`, and only reading the data you *actually want to display*.

Comment: I need to work with all data in file because I need filtering them and sorting them and others. I am using StreamReader and ReadLine. This app is not just for me so fix with faster disk isn´t best solution :)

Comment: @Bibo fine, but if IO performance is the bottleneck there is nothing you can do unless you ***do less IO*** - for example, by changing the file format. Compression (gzip or something) might help - it trades CPU for IO - and most modern machines have plenty enough CPU that this is a net gain.

Comment: @Bibo - it could also be something *in your code* slowing it down (we can't tell w/o code) - but again: NGEN is not a magic bullet for bad code.

Comment: I added code with changing line to class Record. Did you think that compression can help with performance? You mean compression original file? I can´t much change original file because its output of other application.

Comment: @Bibo - well, the first thing I'd do is lose all those `Remove`... creating an army of strings for each row won't help the GC any...

Comment: I have it because I don´t know lenght of each data between ' '. So I find next, get data and remove it to the next ' '. What would be better way?

Comment: @Bibo; I would track the index within the row - but first: have you *profiled* this?

Answer (score 0):

Preformance profiler for load time and memory profiler for memory usage.

http://www.red-gate.com/

They have both tools and a free trial. Nothing more can be said, as your question is without code, so reply without code :)

Comment: It is code on hundreds lines and I hope it´s very good written I just have all data in my own class for each line and all objects in Arraylist and It is store 500MB RAM or more and I want to get it down. I did some analysis with Red gate tool but I am not sure what could I fix. If I post it somewhere, could you help me?

Comment: I added profiler file, I hope filefactory is ok. I have file with memory too but it has 600MB

Comment: meant for you to post the slow code here, not a 10Mb dump file.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be of some use to you regarding how to speed up Winforms application load time:

[Improving Application Startup Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163655.aspx)

If you are loading the entire 200MB text file into memory on load however I'm not sure how much that will help - you should try to find a way to avoid loading large files into memory but how you do that will depend completley on how your application works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with such large datasets, you have to think about **perceived performance**.  For instance, why not do all the work on a background thread using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component and use it's OnProgress event to let the user know its progress.

NGEN and other tricks will only take you so far (really not that far) - you have to realize that you need a different approach.

Comment: I am using BackgroundWorker so I have progress bar but I just want to have less and less time to spend for working and mainly less memory to use.

Comment: @Bibo, then you have to think about what you are displaying to the user.  Do they really need to see 200MB of information at one time?  I am betting not.  At the end of the day, 200MB is going to take up RAM space and time to process - you can't get around that.  You have to consider taking a different approach.

Comment: I don´t need to display it all at once but I need to filtering, sorting it and scrolling (I have it in datagrid, exactly in c1flexgrid).

Comment: I see now.  I think there are 2 approaches.  One is to load your log file into a database of some type and query it from there.  Let the database engine do all the hard work of filtering/sorting/grouping/etc... Second approach is to use virtualization approach.  If I remember correctly from the vb6 days, the c1flexgrid had a Virtual mode where you could load massive amounts of data, but it would only load what's needed.